# C# Interop with __cdecl callbacks and delegates

Tags: c#, interop

I've been successfully working with Interop to work with an external C-library for a while.  It's been great.  We needed to add the ability to work with a function that has a callback.  That's been a bit more challenging.  We've tried passing it as an IntPtr, and a couple of other options.  But it always seems to crash VisualStudio.  We also tried to enable native debugging, but there are no debug libs for the other library, and it just kind of ends there.

Relevant C library code:

```
#define CVICDECL        __cdecl
#define CVICALLBACK     CVICDECL

typedef int32 (CVICALLBACK *DAQmxEveryNSamplesEventCallbackPtr)(TaskHandle taskHandle, int32 everyNsamplesEventType, uInt32 nSamples, void *callbackData);

int32 __CFUNC     DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent(TaskHandle task, int32 everyNsamplesEventType, uInt32 nSamples, uInt32 options, DAQmxEveryNSamplesEventCallbackPtr callbackFunction, void *callbackData);
```

And the C# code:

```
[DllImport("nicaiu", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent(IntPtr task, Int32 everyNsamplesEventType, UInt32 nSamples, UInt32 options, EveryNSamplesCallback callbackFunction, IntPtr callbackData);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate Int32 EveryNSamplesCallback(IntPtr taskHandle, Int32 everyNsamplesEventType, UInt32 nSamples, IntPtr callbackData);
 ...
  func = new EveryNSamplesCallback(Test2Callback); //func is a class-level variable
tmp += ChkForError(DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent(taskHandle_DAT, DAQmx_Val_Transferred_From_Buffer, 104, 0 , func, new IntPtr()));
...
   public Int32 Test2Callback(IntPtr taskHandle, Int32 everyNsamplesEventType, UInt32 nSamples, IntPtr callbackData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CALLBACK!!");
            return 0;
        }
```

We've tried a number of different things (using IntPtr in the signature) and elsewhere, and it always wants to puke on us.  Thoughts on how to implement and/or debug?

Comment: As they mentioned [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabWindows-CVI/taskHandle-TaskHandle/td-p/282319?profile.language=en) it seems TaskHandle is just an integer

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the TaskHandle here at all, and I can assure you that it is an IntPtr.  I have a couple hundred other functions that take taskHandle in and work beautifully.  It's the callback-specific part that appears to be having an issue.

Comment: We can't see the `func` variable declaration, it is crucial that it is `static` so the garbage collector won't collect the delegate object.

Comment: That wouldn't be the cause for this issue -- as the class is fully loaded, and it being a global variable in the class will keep it from being GC'd.  If it was working, and then randomly stopped then you'd look at the GC being the culprit.  But it not working basically the next instruction after creation obviously can't be the GC.  As long as the class is kept alive, and the object a global variable in the class you're going to be ok.  If you make it static, and have multiple of these classes instantiated (which I do), then you're in for a world of hurt...See below solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the MarshalAs statement into the PInvoke prototype worked.  Somehow I guess I assumed that since the Delegate was tagged as that that it would Marshal that way also.  But there's probably a reason why you need to be more explicit.

```
   public static extern int DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent(IntPtr task, Int32 everyNsamplesEventType, UInt32 nSamples, UInt32 options,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]EveryNSamplesCallback callbackFunction, IntPtr callbackData);
```